# django-import-export does not export child class

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I wanted to export the parent class of the models alongside with related child class included, but after exporting csv file, only data from parent class is present except for child class. I'm not sure what did I do wrong.

```
class Membership(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
   email = models.EmailField()

class References(models.Model):
   member = models.ForeignKey('Membership', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
   contact_details = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
```

here's my resources.py

```
class MemberResources(resources.ModelResources):
   reference_name = Field(attribute='name', widget=ForeignKeyWidget(References, 'name')
   class Meta:
      model = Membership
```

admin.py

```
class MembershipAdmin(ExportActionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
   resource_class = MemberResources

admin.site.register(Member, MembershipAdmin)
```

I attempted using ForeignKeyWidget but the `reference_name`  is still blank even theres data inside the instance

Comment: have you tried the [`fields`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#exporting-data) attribute to control which fields are exported?  You can reference FK fields with double underscore: e.g.`member__name`

Comment: Yep I tried that, apparently I found out what I needed to do was to perform a reverse foreign key on this by using _set.all()